# Cassandra: Is this proper schema for the data model?

Tags: cassandra, schema

In a sensor-based application, up to 300k objects are being monitored per hour on up to 30 metrics each having success and failure counters.

My schema:

```
CREATE TABLE measurements(
  objId int,
  hour timestamp,
  metric text,
  succ int,
  fail int,
  PRIMARY KEY (objId, hour, metric));
```

Data retention period is within 1 year, this way the table would have 300k rows each having 24*360*30*2 columns(cells).

Usual queries are to get counter values aggregated over specified time interval (could be days, weeks, months) and specified objects (ranging from 1 to hundreds).

Time slicing is perfectly OK with column slicing, while retrieval of multiple objects are a bit pain, since rows are keyed per object by objId and that would lead to multiget.

The general query I can think of is:

```
select * from measurements where objId in (id1, id2, id3...idn) and hour >= <startTime> and hour < <endTime>;
```

of course the aggregation would have to be done manually in application.

Q: is this an optimal way to structure the data given the query pattern?

Worst case is to get 'overall' result over a period, that means taking ALL objects into account. That would mean, from my perspective, a full table scan. Any recommended practice to perform such task w/o resorting to MapReduce?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you typically will be restricting a subset of time and the possible set of objects within each hour may be sparse, you might consider reversing the index order, so that time is the first dimension.  This way, you would be picking out columns from a restricted set of rows, so you will still need a multi-get, but if querying for all objects is common, then the number of rows may be smaller.

If you typically query/aggregate to different granularities of time, you could also store duplicate data at higher granularities of time as well, like per day, week, month, etc.  This could significantly speed up queries for larger time scales.  De-normalization is your friend in Cassandra!

It's possible that you keep around indices for both orderings and choose the index based upon the type of query you are performing.

Comment: fully agree with pre-aggregation on different granularites. however having time as row key will lose much desired column slicing on time line.